# Display Japanese Character from Encoded URL

Tags: php

I was doing a small task on php (Even tried the same task on cold-fusion).

There is an API that sends me URL of following Pattern as a data:

1. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/index.php?brand=%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4`
2. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/index.php?brand=Airtel%20India%20Mobile%20Corporation`

I have to display the brand name, which is crucial part of the task. When I simply prints brand name as:

```
echo $_GET['brand']
```

, than I am getting correct output for URL 2.

URL 2 prints **Airtel India Mobile Corporation**.

However, I am getting wrong output for 1.
URL 1 prints weird set of characters. Please Note URL-1 brand contains name of a Japanese company(Nissan Motor Co., Ltd.) in Japanese.

URL 1 : **echo** prints

> “úŽYŽ©“®ŽÔ

I realized its an encoding problem. Then What I did is:

**Right-Clicked on IE**->Selected **Encoding**-> Selected **Japanese(Shift_JIS)** as Encoding.

As soon as I selected **Japanese(Shift_JIS)**, I got the correct output.

> 日産自動車

How can I do it using PHP (and/or) Cold-Fusion? In other words, how can I display correct/desired o/p by PHP( or coldfusion) code (script).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use this function.

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

```
$str = $_GET["brand"]; //%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "SJIS", "auto");
echo $str; //日産自動車
```

**EDITED**

```
$str = $_GET["brand"]; //%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4
$str = urldecode($str);
echo $str; //日産自動車
```

This should work.

There is "urlencode" function that do the opposite thing of "urldecode" function as well.

Comment: ``$str = $_GET["brand"]; //%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4
$str = urldecode($str);
echo $str; //日産自動車 ``. This displayed “úŽYŽ©“®ŽÔ

Comment: `` $str = $_GET["brand"]; //%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "SJIS", "auto");
echo $str; //日産自動車 `` threw Warning: mb_convert_encoding(): Unable to detect character encoding in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 3

Comment: the second one I posted worked for me. I tested it before I posted.

Comment: Can you just copy & paste this and see if it works?

<?php

$str = "%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4";
$str = urldecode($str);
echo $str;

?>

Comment: `<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<?php
 $str = $_GET["brand"]; //%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4
 echo "In UTF-8 W/o Coversion".$str."<br>";
 
 $str = mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8',"SJIS");
 echo $str; //日産自動車
?>` , worked for me. Thanks for the help. I will accept this answer as it provided me path to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this is used on a proper website, you should add that encoding to the `charset` attribute of your HTML header. If it's just a test page that echoes out that string then the browser will just use default encoding.

```
<meta charset="shift_js">
```